# Cropping the strings in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list which the super-cropped version looks like this:

```
b=['5:18:00',
 '5:19:00',
 '5:20:00',
 '5:21:00',
 '11:31:00',
 '11:32:00',
 '11:33:00',
 '0:01:00',
 '0:02:00',
 '0:03:00']
```

I want to keep the hours, and eliminate the rest.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: take a look at string split method.

Comment: This is fairly simple. Have you had a look at the datetime module?

Comment: Well, no. I've not worked with that module. What command should I use?

Comment: `[i.split(":")[0] for i in b]`

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python split" or "Python slice", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.
Any tutorial on string processing would answer this.

Answer (score 0):

```
b=['5:18:00',
 '5:19:00',
 '5:20:00',
 '5:21:00',
 '11:31:00',
 '11:32:00',
 '11:33:00',
 '0:01:00',
 '0:02:00',
 '0:03:00']

b=[i.split(":")[0] for i in b]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` module:

```
import datetime as dt

[dt.datetime.strptime(i, '%H:%M:%S').hour for i in b]
# [5, 5, 5, 5, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with `datetime`

Example:

```
for time in b:

    print(datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M:%S").hour)
```